# How to add infos to library's log message?

Tags: java, logging, dependencies, static-libraries

I have a `Servlet` that uses a Library. Both servlet and library log things via log4j.
The servlet is multithreaded and **each request has a unique "request ID"** like `123456`.
When the servlet is logging stuff, it always appends the request ID at the beginning of the log message, but the library does not.
Like this:
`Servlet - [123456] I'm going to do stuff now and call the library
LibraryX - I do library stuff here`

**How can I also append this request ID to every library message log, without modifying the library ?**
What I want is :
`Servlet - [123456] I'm going to do stuff now and call the library
LibraryX - [123456] I do library stuff here`

Comment: Have you looked at [log4j2 Thread Context](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html)? I think it can be usefull for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Mapped Diagnostic Context](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html)
Just put your requestId into the context:

```
MDC.put("requestId", requestId);
```

And configure your `jog4j.xml`

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d - [%X{requestId}] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```